# Can't find Watson Assistant login

Tags: authentication, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am probably being thick, but I can't find where to log into my Watson Assistant account in the UK.  Please help!  I have tried googling and ibm search and help.  None of it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to IBM Cloud, you should see your dashboard of services. One will say Watson Assistant and when you click that there should be a button for Launch tool.

If you can let me know which part of that process you're missing that will help.

Comment: You log into the IBM Cloud console - from there, you just enter the Watson Assistant instance.
If you are trying to "log in" programmatically, then use the API keys.

Comment: My Dashboard has a box that says "Resource Summary".  There is one service listed, and when I click on that it takes me to a page that has nothing about Watson Assistant.

Comment: My Dashboard has a box that says "Resource Summary".  There is one service listed, and when I click on that it takes me to a page that has nothing about Watson Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get to the GUI tool, then you're on the right path with the list of resources.

In the Resource summary panel, click **[Services](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources)**, and then click the name of the Watson Assistant service instance that you created. From that instance details page you should see a "Launch Watson Assistant button that links the tool.

[image: /resources]